# Azure Function Linux Nodejs and @azure/storage-blob gives error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am testing my Azure Nodejs Linux function locally and this code:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const connectionString = process.env[
  "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
] as string;

export const blobServiceClient =
  BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
```

is generating this error message:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/myApp/code/seal/azure_function$ rm -rf dist/ && npm run-script build &&  func start 

> azure_function@1.0.0 build /Users/john/myApp/code/seal/azure_function
> tsc && tsc-alias


Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667


Functions:

        sealworker: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/sealworker

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.440Z] Worker was unable to load entry point "dist/sealworker/index.js": Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.551Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.564Z] Worker was unable to load function sealworker: 'Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined'
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z] Worker failed to load function: 'sealworker' with functionId: 'c146c9d1-05ef-4aa2-bb18-d436186b7f65'.
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z] Result: Failure
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z] Exception: Worker was unable to load function sealworker: 'Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined'
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z] Stack: TypeError: Worker was unable to load function sealworker: 'Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined'
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z]     at extractConnectionStringParts (/Users/john/myApp/code/seal/azure_function/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:13654:26)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.568Z]     at Function.fromConnectionString (/Users/john/myApp/code/seal/azure_function/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:24328:32)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/myApp/code/seal/azure_function/dist/sealworker/utils/Azure/blobServiceClient.js:6:62)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Object.apply (/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.5198/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js:2:44135)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.569Z]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/myApp/code/seal/azure_function/dist/sealworker/services/attachment.js:58:29)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.571Z]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.571Z]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.571Z]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.571Z]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.571Z]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19).
[2023-08-15T09:06:03.785Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000DB4F1B81'.
^C[2023-08-15T09:34:22.578Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=53985.
[2023-08-15T09:34:22.578Z] node exited with code 130 (0x82). .
```

`connectionString` is defined as a string:

```
const connectionString = process.env[
  "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
] as string;
```

However the complain is `Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

Not sure what I should do now...
Any hints?

Comment: You can directly set the connection string to your storage account like below- process.env["AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "<your_connection_string>";

Comment: One more option is to set the connection string in your local.settings.json and retrive it in your function code like here- const connectionString = process.env["AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"];

Comment: Also, If you want to interact with blob trigger you can directly use blob trigger Azure Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use azure blob package in Http Trigger, Use the code below:-

*Typescript function Http Trigger:-*

**index.ts:-**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  context.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  const connectionString = process.env[
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
  ] as string;

  const blobServiceClient =
    BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

  // Your code here

  context.res = {
    // Your response here
  };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

***My local.settings.json:-***

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<strgaccountname>;AccountKey=xxxxxxKImyt8HTQ6Dp3zVaDMTexxxUwASRw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "kamstore_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<strgaccountname>;AccountKey=xxxxzVaDMTelk/ae+AStUwASRw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<strgaccountname>;AccountKey=xxxxHTQ6Dp3zVaDMTelk/ae+AStUwASRw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

**Local:-**

[image]

[image]

Another option is to set the setting in your terminal with the command below:-

```bash
export  AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="<your_connection_string>"
```

In your Function app you can add this setting in your configuration tab like below:-

[image]

Reference - [Get started with Azure Blob Storage and TypeScript - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-typescript-get-started?tabs=azure-ad)

Alternatively you can use [blob trigger1](https://github.com/marcduiker/azure-functions-university/blob/main/lessons/typescript/blob/README.md)  and [blob trigger2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript,linux,azure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4) with Typescript which trigger azure function when new blob is added in the storage account and perform your processing.

**Portal in nodejs Linux Function app:-**

[image]

**HttpTrigger:-**

[image]

**BlobTrigger:-**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The error message doesn't seems useful in this case. Adding `local.settings.json` resolved the problem in my case.